# how to pass multi-array arguments to jquery for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show my `overlay`s when hovering over `item`s.

This the code:

```html
<div class="item" id="item-1">
    <div class="overlay" id="overlay-1"></div>
</div>
<div class="item" id="item-2">
    <div class="overlay" id="overlay-2"></div>
</div>
```

```js
var items=["#item-1","#item-2"];
var overlays=["#overlay-1","#overlay-2"];
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  $(items[i]).hover(
    function(){$(overlays[i]).css("visibility", "visible");},
    function(){$(overlays[i]).css("visibility", "hidden");});
}
```

however, it doesn't work...
it seams that `overlays[i]` can't be recognized...

why?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this

```
$(".item").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".overlay").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it is a scoping issue where the overlays you are trying to select are out of scope.

You could eliminate the need to explicitly loop over the items altogether by just apply the hover to the "item" class and the hide/show logic to the "overlay" class. Additionally, to hide and show items, the jQuery friendly pattern is to use the hide and show methods.

```
$('div.item').hover(function(){
    var overlay = $(this).children('div.overlay');
    overlay.hide();
});
overlay.hide();
},
function(){
    var overlay = $(this).children('div.overlay');
    overlay.show();
});
```

With out knowing all of the details, you should know that this approach could produce some unwanted flickering.

Answer (score -1):

It's a closure issue. By the time the hover in/out functions actually run, the loop has long since exited, and `i > 2`.

Add a separate handler function:

```
var items=["#item-1","#item-2"];
var overlays=["#overlay-1","#overlay-2"];

function sethover(n) {
  $(items[n]).hover(
    function(){$(overlays[n]).css("visibility", "visible");},
    function(){$(overlays[n]).css("visibility", "hidden");});
}

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  sethover(i);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    $(items[i]).hover(function(){
        $(this).find('.overlay').css("visibility", "visible");
    }, function(){
        $(this).find('.overlay').css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
}
```